# AJAX: call existing JS function/set variable based on PHP script return

Tags: php, ajax, callback

I have an HTML form I was tasked with updating..
It needs to be able to have a discount code applied, and the total updated (before being submitted)

I am using AJAX to:

- grab the discount code input by the user in the form field.
- send this piece of data to an external .php script
- .php script checks the discount, and returns either true or false
- upon the return of this data/(php) response, I set a JS var, and call an existing function to update some things on the 'page'

My current problem is that I can NOT set this var.. NOR call this existing function from the return/success function in the my AJAX call.

Upon searching before posting..  (and as I understand it this is at least partially my problem)..  I get the AJAX is Asynchronous.. and the 'doMath() function is probably being called/executed BEFORE the php response is sent back)..

But I still dont get why the var isnt being updated when I set it then check it? In the 'success' callback??

I read about setting async to false..

as in:

```
$.ajax({
   async: false,
   type: "POST",
```

But also read that this is a BAD approach and should be avoided..

is there a different or better callback to use when all is 'said and done'?  instead of using success perhaps??

TO re-cap:

- not able to set a var OUTSIDE of the AJAX function/call
- not able to execute/call an existing function

Here is the PHP in case its needed (for full disclosure)

```
$dicountcode = 'code_to_match';
$submittedDiscount = $_POST['var1'];

if($submittedDiscount == $dicountcode){
    //echo 'TRUE: '.$submittedDiscount;
    echo 'true';
}else{
    //echo 'False: '.$submittedDiscount;
    echo 'false';
}
```

And really most of the AJAX stuff is working outside the two items mentioned above.

Here my code/approach:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" language="JavaScript">

var doDiscount = false;

//math operations
function dothemath() {  
    //do some math stuff here
    //update the page with the new 'amount'

    //** uses the above doDiscount var status to knwo wheather to apply a discount or not
}


function applyDiscount(){
    //make ajax call and send data to PHP script for discount checking
        alert("'else' routine executed...");
        $.ajax({
            //async: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "conservationmanual_discount.php",
            //datatype: "html",
            datatype: "text",
            data:{
                //var1: "My Discount Code"
                "disCode": $('#discountcode').val()
            },
            success: function(response) {
                alert("PHP RETURN CHECK: "+response);
                if(response == "true"){
                    alert("Discount Code is Valid.");
                    //update var
                    doDiscount = true;
                    //update discount status icon
                    $("#discountStaus").html(
                        "<img src='greencheck.png' />"
                    );

                    //check doDiscount status after 'update'
                    console.log("DO DISCOUNT STATUS: "+doDiscount);
                    //calculate/update total:
                    dothemath();
                }else{
                    alert("Discount Code is not Valid.");
                    //update discount status icon
                    $("#discountStaus").html(
                        "<img src='redx.png' />"
                    );
                    //leave as is/do nothing
                    console.log("DO DISCOUNT STATUS: "+doDiscount);
                }
            }
        });
    }




</script>
```

Update:

Also.. the deeper I debug, I seem to NOT be able to use the response in a conditional check.

ie:

```
success: function(response) {
                    alert("PHP RETURN CHECK: "+response);
                    if(response == "true"){
                        alert("Discount Code is Valid.");
                        //update var
                        doDiscount = true;
                        //update discount status icon
                        $("#discountStaus").html(
                            "<img src='greencheck.png' />"
                        );

                        //check doDiscount status after 'update'
                        console.log("DO DISCOUNT STATUS: "+doDiscount);
                        //calculate/update total:
                        dothemath();
```

How does one use the PHP response/return data in a conditional?

```
response == "true"
```

seems to NEVER be true?  Although my ALERTS, show 'response' to be true:

```
alert("PHP RETURN CHECK: "+response);
```

but the immediate conditional check after it is always false???  (probbaly why I am not able to set the var correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just passing the doDiscount value you need to the `dotheMath()` function. I don't see any compelling reason for you to store the value in global scope. That change may be as simple as:

So the math function might look like this:

```
function dothemath(doDiscount) {
   //
}
```

And your success handler might look like:

```
    success: function(data) {
        dotheMath(data);
    }
```

Note that I don't have any conditionals there, as I am assuming the `dotheMath()` function would handle both true and false cases, since that is what you were wanting to do via your `doDiscount` variable.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but why CAN'T I update the var that is outside AJAX function from its response routine?

Also updated initial post...

Comment: Update:  for anyone else who has trouble parsing/using the php return data in any sort of conditional, (for me) the fix was:


`if($.trim(response) == 'true'){`

without the trim() part... 

My conditional check here:


`if(response == "true"){`

was NEVER true!  (not sure where the garbage is coming from?)